# SQL Server 2016 - Always Encrypted - Missing Option To Generate Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ssms, sql-server-2016, always-encrypted

I'm currently testing Always Encrypted feature of SQL Server 2016, and I was able to encrypt the column using default keys but I am unable to script this effort out via "Generate PowerShell script to run later" option.

[image]

Has anyone encountered and re-mediated this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working in my environment:

[image]

I think I have similar issue because I was not using the latest `SQL Server Management Studio`. You can find the latest version [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms).

The generated code looks like this - I think you can change it and try if you cannot save as PS script:

```
# Generated by SQL Server Management Studio at 9:15 AM on 2017-10-09

Import-Module SqlServer
# Set up connection and database SMO objects

$sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=SQLInstanceName\INST1;Initial Catalog=databaseName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;Packet Size=4096;Application Name=`"Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio`""
$smoDatabase = Get-SqlDatabase -ConnectionString $sqlConnectionString

# If your encryption changes involve keys in Azure Key Vault, uncomment one of the lines below in order to authenticate:
#   * Prompt for a username and password:
#Add-SqlAzureAuthenticationContext -Interactive

#   * Enter a Client ID, Secret, and Tenant ID:
#Add-SqlAzureAuthenticationContext -ClientID '<Client ID>' -Secret '<Secret>' -Tenant '<Tenant ID>'

# Change encryption schema

$encryptionChanges = @()

# Add changes for table [dbo].[TablenameX]
$encryptionChanges += New-SqlColumnEncryptionSettings -ColumnName dbo.TablenameX.columNameX -EncryptionType Deterministic -EncryptionKey "CEK_Auto1"

Set-SqlColumnEncryption -ColumnEncryptionSettings $encryptionChanges -InputObject $smoDatabase
```

The SQL version is:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) - 13.0.4001.0 (X64)   Oct
>   28 2016 18:17:30      Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation     Enterprise
>   Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2
>   Standard 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

And the SSMS version is `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 14.0.17177.0` - or v17.2 from the link I have provided.

Comment: Thank you man, I will keep you posted if i can test this under SSMS 2016 because the instance is actually MS SQL 13(2016).

Comment: Note, now the installation of SSMS is not part of the SQL Server installation. You can download the file from the link for free and install it - having two version of SSMS is OK, too.

Comment: dude, can i ask for your Instance version(SQL server) and your SSMS version? im using SSMS 2016 but still getting same behavior @gotqn

Comment: @CarlArdiente Yes, check the edit. You need to update the SSMS

Comment: Seems like its truly is an SSMS issue. While waiting for the upgrade, ive tested the powershell approach and got this error:
`Set-SqlColumnEncryption : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:27 char:3`

But i can see that I did supply the right parameters
`Set-SqlColumnEncryption -ColumnEncryptionSettings $encryptionChanges -InputObject $smoDatabase`

have you tried executing the powershell from your end? @gotqn

Comment: Yes. I have tested various of cases of power shell files - using different key store providers. Most of the scripts are included in msdn, also. I really recommend to update to SQL Server 2016 SP1 and SSMS 17.2 - it's new technology and a lot of issues are fixed constantly.